# Excel to formula to generate number series pattern

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to generate a number series with pattern

> a+3*1=b
>      b+3*3=c

and so on where

- a=any integer
- and any constant number like 3 here and multiplied by 1,3,5 so on.
- The number should increment as we drag down the rows.

I have done a similar one with but unable to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pls post what tried so far.

Comment: The `ROW()` function will give you the number of the current row. Use that in place of the variable in your series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you've worked out the simple solution with helper column, but here it 
is nonetheless. Assuming "a" in your question is manually entered in cell A1:
then in B1:

```
=A1+3*1
```

and in B2 and following:

```
=B1+3*C2
```

Column C wil have your sequence of odd numbers.

Here's a solution with no helper column. B1 will remain the same as previous, whereas B2 becomes:

```
=B1+3*(ROW(B2)+ROW(B1))
```

Notes that this formula need to start on row 2.

Comment: Thank you very much pomul. That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.